# How to get to another Listview from selected item in previous Listview?

Tags: android, listview

Newbie here. Greetings everyone. I want to develop an app where it first displays a list of states in Malaysia, then when a state is selected, another list which displays the name of schools in that state pops out. So far I've managed the first part. How do I get to the second part? I've done some research but I'm still lost. Suggestions, examples and tutorial links are much appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Initialize the array
    String[] states = { "Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur", "Federal Territory of Labuan", "Federal Territory of Putrajaya", 
                       "Johor", "Kedah", "Kelantan", "Malacca", "Negeri Sembilan", "Pahang", "Perak", "Perlis", "Penang",
                       "Sabah", "Sarawak", "Selangor", "Terengganu" };

    // Declare the UI components
    private ListView statesListView;

    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize the UI components
        statesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, states);

        // By using setAdapter method, you plugged the ListView with adapter
        statesListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this tutorial will help.http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

Comment: If the answer satisfied your needs,you can accept by click on tick symbol on left side of the answer.